# i cant type the xml in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

this is my xml file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <OTA_Langee xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05 OTA_VehResRS.xsd" Version="2.001"><information><Descriptions>bla bla bla
    <Dis1>bla bla bla</Dis1>
    </Descriptions></information></OTA_Langee>
```

and this is my php file

```
    <?php 

 $xml = simplexml_load_file('deneme.xml');

echo $xml->information;

?>
```

but nothin display when i run .. i want write between  data.. but it does not type anything.. any help please?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on for your PHP code ? Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: Also, what do you get when you do `var_dump($xml)` ? I am not entirely sure but it is possible that your XML file is  not formatted correctly. Is that all that there is to the file or is there more ?

Comment: that's all my codes.. nothing more..it display only white page.. nothing more..:(

Comment: Never mind. Looks like at least the XML file is correct.

Comment: here the var_dump details ;

'object(SimpleXMLElement)[1]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=1)
      'Version' => string '2.001' (length=5)
  public 'information' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
      public 'Descriptions' => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
   public 'D1' => string 'bla bla' (length=73)'

Comment: Look at the answer by FirstOne below. You are getting the information that you need but you are not displaying it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `information` still has a `descriptions`. This is the output for `print_r($xml)`:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [Version] => 2.001
        )

    [information] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Descriptions] => bla bla bla


        )

)
```

So you'd access it like this:

```
echo $xml->information->Descriptions;
```

Output:

> bla bla bla

---

Instead of `echo`, if you use `print_r` on `$xml->information`, you'll get this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Descriptions] => bla bla bla


)
```

Comment: @UmutBulut, no problem, glad to help :D

Comment: There's no malformed XML here. `print_r` just can't represent the internals of a SimpleXML object very well, so shows *either* text content *or* child nodes, but never both. The content is there, and accessible just fine, as you showed yourself. `<Dis1>` would be accessed with `echo $xml->information->Descriptions->Dis1`.